# How to ask clarification of edits during review

Tags: support, review-queues

Sometimes, when I'm reviewing edits for approval/rejection, I really would like to ask the editor for clarification on the *why* of certain choices.

Can it be done?

Comment: No, it can't be done.

Comment: All reviews are meant to be standalone as well. if the choices are questionable enough to warrant rejection, reject it. If you're unsure, there's no shame in using skip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeating [what Zoe said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421484/how-to-ask-clarification-of-edits-during-review#comment934139_421484), so we can put this one to bed.

> All reviews are meant to be standalone as well. If the choices are questionable enough to warrant rejection, reject it. If you're unsure, there's no shame in using skip.